# Plesk SSH Ftp command

Tags: ssh, ftp, plesk

I know that's not completely programming question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I'm trying to run the 'ftp' command via shell on my new virtual host, logged in as root user but I'm getting the following error:

> -bash: ftp: command not found

Any idea how I can install / enable ftp command for shell?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ncftp` or `sudo yum install ncftp` or similar depending on your distro.

Comment: Thanks Burhan - I tried it, but got the following response: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.rmg.io
 * extras: mirror.rmg.io
 * updates: mirror.prolocation.net
Setting up Install Process
No package ncftp available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: but when I changed ncftp to 'ftp' it did work - thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use debian:

```
apt-get install ftp
```

on centos

```
yum install ftp
```

Or try LFTP its better:

```
apt-get install lftp

yum install lftp
```